# How do I update my h2o version on AWS working with flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, h2o

I installed h2o using the AMI on the marketplace.   It installed 3.14, and I am trying to update the version to the latest stable one of h2o.ai so my co-workers can use flow.   How can I best do this?

I have tried uninstalling using

```
pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/4/Python/h2o-3.18.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

And directly by SSH-ing into my instance via terminal.  However, even if it says "successfully uninstalled", it seems to keep reverting to the version 3.14.

I suspect there is a script at startup that is reinstalling and loading 3.14, but I can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you asking about using H2O in Flow and then also talking about the Python module?  Are you using H2O from Flow or from Python (or both)?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to update flow. I am unsure how to do that, and assumed (probably incorrectly) that it was build on top of the python implementation.